Flutter Semantics showing empty array for scrollview
I am facing a problem with Flutter semantics with the scroll view. If there is a SingleChildScrollView of ListView the flutter semantics announce an unlabeled item.
The code is really simple.
 ListView.builder(
                          controller: _scrollController,
                          itemCount: 10,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                          return Container(width: 100, height 200);
                          }

I have attached a screenshot of what the Accessibility inspector is giving me. Under that, you can see there is a FlutterSemanticScrollView object is created.

The issue only occurs when there is enough content available for scrolling.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Try to used Sementic instead of Container
return Semantics(
      label: 'Item ${index + 1}',
      hint: 'Double tap to interact',
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 200,
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
    child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Item ${index + 1}',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );


It doesn't help me. Actually the Container I have added in the question is a dummy widget. It is actually a Semantic widget.
